# Summing elements of a list that are placed only on an even number position

Tags: python, list, sum, range

I want to sum the elements of a list that are placed only on an even number position.

This is what I have, but it doesn't seam to work.

```
code=input("SVP entrez le code :")
r=range(0,11,2)
sum=(sum(i) for i in r)
print(sum)
```

Comment: It also overwrites the built-in `sum` function, so if you ever needed that again, it will be gone until you restart your python session.

Comment: Related: [creating sum of odd indexes python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823625/creating-sum-of-odd-indexes-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting a error like below,

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

this is because you are trying to sum each variable (int) in the range,

But the syntax of sum() is:

```
sum(iterable, start)
```

If you pass the range directly to sum method, it will give you the correct output, also try not to use **sum** as name for variable, below change should get the answer you are looking for, good luck

```
code=input("SVP entrez le code :")
r=range(0,11,2)
my_sum=sum(r)
print(my_sum)
```

more information on the sum can be found here https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sum

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I'm assuming you are starting at `0` if not just use `[2::2]`

```
code = int(input("Enter code: "))
numbers = []
for i in (str(code)):
    numbers.append(int(i))
total = sum(numbers[::2])
print(total)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 code.py 
> Enter code: 123456
> 9
> ```